# Using nested OR statements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nested, case

I'm working with SQL Server 2008, and trying to query 1 table based on the following criteria: (any help would be appreciated!)

Here is the logic of what I am trying to achieve, but am having difficulty applying the OR statements within the CASE statements....

```
IF (**PD** within 90 days)
AND 
(
(**SACLMD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days)
OR
    ((**PD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days) OR (**PDLMD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days))
OR
    ((**SD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days) OR (**SDLMD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days))
OR
    ((**CD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days) OR (**CDLMD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days))
OR  
    ((**AD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days) OR (**ADLMD** IS NOT NULL AND within 90 days))
)
AND (**LL** IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Can you provide *some* idea of what the query, table structure, and data look like?

Comment: You don't need any of those `IS NOT NULL` checks when combined with an `AND` - the other half of the condition can only be true if the value is not NULL. Also the inner check of PD is redundant, isn't it? This whole sub-condition is ANDed with a condition that states that PD must be within 90 days (and therefore not NULL).